# array update in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got mongoose schema like this:

```
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: String,
    photos: [{
       url: String,
       thumbnail: String,
       time: Date,
       mainPhoto: Boolean
    }]
});
```

now, I'd like to make a "setMainPhoto" function - for given id - set mainPhoto flag to true, and set it to false for other photos.
There is a document like this:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "56269dea07a455920a21bca7"
},
"user": "someUser",
"photos": [
    {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2015-05-25T08:37:56.000Z"
        },
        "thumbnail": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56269e2e07a455920a21bcab"
        },
        "mainPhoto": false
    },
    {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2015-05-25T09:27:17.000Z"
        },
        "thumbnail": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56269e3507a455920a21bcae"
        },
        "mainPhoto": true
    },
    {
        "time": {
            "$date": "2015-05-25T09:27:17.000Z"
        },
        "thumbnail": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "url": "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/...jpg",
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56269e3507a455920a21bcaf"
        },
        "mainPhoto": false
    }
 ]}
```

I'm trying to do this with mongoose save function:

```
var myModel = mongoose.model('myCollection', mySchema);
myModel.find({user:params.user,_id:params.documentId}, function(err,data){
    var newMyModel = new myModel(data[0]);

    for(var i=0; i<newMyModel.photos.length; i++){
        if(newMyModel.photos[i]._id == params.photoId){
            newMyModel.photos[i].mainPhoto = true;
        }else{
            newMyModel.photos[i].mainPhoto = false;
        }
    }

    return newTrack.save(function(err,results){
      console.log(err,results);
      return cb(err,results);
    });
  });
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
 'E11000 duplicate key error index: xx.$_id_ dup key: { : ObjectId(\'56269dea07a455920a21bca7\') }',
```

apart from the fact I feel there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try a conditional type of update operation that first updates the documents based on the given criteria using the **[`.update()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update)** method with a callback, and then do the other update in the callback for documents that do not satisfy the given criteria. For example, you could restructure this as:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('myCollection', mySchema);
Model.update(
    {
        "_id": params.documentId,
        "user": params.user,
        "photos.mainPhoto": true            
    }, 
    {
        "$set": {
            "photos.$.mainPhoto": false
        }
    },        
    function(err, numAffected) {        
        Model.update(
            {
                "_id": params.documentId,
                "user": params.user,
                "photos._id": params.photoId /* criteria for setting the updating the documents to true */
            }, 
            {
                "$set": {
                    "photos.$.mainPhoto": true
                }
            },
            function(err, numAffected) {
                /* Update complete. */
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. That didn't work for me, but after 2 changes it did. This line: "photos._id": { "$ne": params.photoId } I had to remove, so I did it by reversing order - first - set mainFlag to false, then in second step to true. Also - parameter multi: true - doesn't work for me, but that is ok, as I have only one mainPhoto. So those conditions are: "photos.mainPhoto": true - changing to false, and:

"photos._id": params.photoId - changing to true

thank you.

Comment: @JakubPałach Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer to reflect the changes, let me know if the changes are correct and work on your angle.